# How to use Environment without @Autowired in java Spring?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I want use environment property in `MyLoginSuccessHandler` class that is used in SpringSecurity.

You know, `MyLoginSuccessHandler` implements `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

But, most examples show usage of `@autowired` like below.

```java
@Autowired
private Environment env;
```

But autowired env variable is null. Because this is login success handler not controller.

I wish to know initialize environment object without `@Autowired` annotation. I want to use env object to access a property in `application.yml`.

If you are alright, please describe how `@Autowired` works. Sometimes I face such this situation, but I do not know how it works.

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is a controller or not. The important part is that it needs to be a spring managed bean. If it is isn't dependencies won't be injected.

Comment: `Environment` is a bean in spring,you can use `@Autowired` to auto inject or use `SpringContext.getBean(name)` to get.

Comment: Do you use `Environment` class to read properties?